# How to remove the dotted focus rectangle from TListBox?

Tags: delphi, canvas, listbox, ownerdrawn

I am using `ListBox.Style := lbOwnerDrawFixed` with `OnDrawItem`:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  with ListBox1.Canvas do begin
    Brush.Color := clWhite;
    Pen.Color := clWhite;
    FillRect(ARect);
  end;
end;
```

It should give an empty space to draw anything I want, but it doesn't. When the item is focued I still can see a dotted rectangle around it.

How to remove the rectangle?

Comment: What about `Brush.Style := bsSolid;` and `Pen.Style := psSolid;`?

Comment: @JerryDodge No change :(

Comment: Only other guess, are you sure `ListBox1` is the same control that's calling this event handler? Typically you should do `TListBox(Control).Canvas` instead of directly referencing the control. Does it show colors when you use another color?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, it's the right control. I added some drawing there to draw text, rectangles and it all works. But after my drawing a default rectangle that indicates the item is selected is being drawn. Looks like the system drawing is happening after my drawing. I just moved my code to DrawGrid and it does only my drawing, no default focus indicators there. Seems like a bug in TListBox to me.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a bug. This is a system control. This is normal behaviour. Owner draw has you draw some part of the control, not all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then I would say this control was badly designed because it makes no sense to custom draw on it in some situations.

Comment: It's not custom draw. It's owner draw.

Comment: http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9909/Owner-drawn_list_boxes.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The focus rectangle is drawn by the VCL <sup>(*)</sup> in `TCustomListBox.CNDrawItem` *after* the `OnDrawItem` event handler returns.

```
procedure TCustomListBox.CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem); 

...

  ..
    if Integer(itemID) >= 0 then
      DrawItem(itemID, rcItem, State)      //-> calls message handler
    else
      FCanvas.FillRect(rcItem);
    if (odFocused in State) and not TStyleManager.IsCustomStyleActive then
      DrawFocusRect(hDC, rcItem);          //-> draws focus rectangle
  ..
..
```

Whatever you draw in the event handler will later get *focused* by the VCL.

But notice that VCL use [`DrawFocusRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to draw the focus rectangle:

> Because **DrawFocusRect** is an XOR function, calling it a second time
>   with the same rectangle removes the rectangle from the screen.

So just call `DrawFocusRect` yourself and let VCL's call erase it:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  with ListBox1.Canvas do begin
    Brush.Color := clWhite;
    Pen.Color := clWhite;
    FillRect(ARect);
    if odFocused in State then  // also check for styles if there's a possibility of using ..
      DrawFocusRect(ARect);
  end;
end;
```

---

<sup>(*) Normally default window procedure draws the focus rectangle for an owner drawn list box item in response to a `WM_DRAWITEM` message. But the default window procedure is not called for a list box in VCL's handling of the message.</sup>